# How to download anonymously with Transmission?

Tags: 16.04, transmission, tor

How to download torrents anonymously with Transmission? I also have Tor browser.

Comment: Transmission doesn't support network proxies (anymore) and therefore cannot work through Tor or other proxied network connections. See [Transmission tracker and/or torrent traffic through proxy](/q/63150/175814).

Comment: Also, please don't use peer-to-peer routing networks like Tor for cheap access to entertainment, because you're taking away bandwidth from people who need it to access locally censored information or evade persecution for their political activity.

Comment: Yeah I know that Tor cannot be used for downloading torrents. I just wanted to know can I download anonymously with transmission because most of the VPNs are not free